# How to parse form data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have been assigned to build a form in flat html but parses a small bit of info to a dynamic (asp) page.

Can i do this in Javascript?

I have looked at quite a few question on SO but nothing answers what I need.

Please can you assist.

I have managed to create this simple form, how do I parse info the user clicks on.

```
<form id='sampleform' method='post' action='myurl.com' >
   <p>
   Name: <input type='text' name='Name' />
   </p>
   <p>
   Email: <input type='text' name='Email' />
   </p>
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="maths" /> &pound;10
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="physics" /> &pound;5
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="physics" /> &pound;3
&pound;<input type='text' name='donate-amount' />
   <p>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
   </p>
</form>
```

Comment: How about jQuery's `serialize()`? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Do you have any markup already? Forms submit to the server by default, you don't need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Hello, no i don't have the script for that yet but I wanted to prepare. To be honest i found this quite a bit awkward to do. Can it be done in flat HTML?

Comment: Just to confirm, what you want is to *pass* the values to the server-side script, not *parse*, right?

Comment: when you a user chooses the field they want, that value then passes to another form which on on the main site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript, HTML forms are made to submit data to the server.

Try this HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="somescript.asp">
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Send to server!">
</form>
```

On the server end, the `Request` object will contain the value of `first_name` when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for this I kind of get it, it hasn't worked how i wanted it too but i will keep going, thanks.